# Does it make sense to define commands like "\xa" to type "$X_1$"?

Tags: best-practices

i.e. in the preamble defining some command like

```
\newcommand{\xa}{$X_1$}
```

I realize this question doesn't have a definite answer -- it is a personal preference kind of thing -- I am just curious if this is something that people view as useful or as bad practice.

I tend to define such commands -- if I am using notation like "$X_1"$ often -- because typing

```
\xa
```

requires me to click 3 buttons as opposed to the 9 for "$X_1$" (shift + 4, shift + x, shift + -, 1, shift + 4)

(yes, it is less than 9 if I hold shift between letters, but its still >3)

---

Edit: I realize that using

```
\newcommand{\xa}{X_1}
```

is perhaps better because then I can use the command in math mode without worrying about things like "$$" happening

Comment: This *is* a matter of personal preference.  For this particular string, it could be more efficient to use `\newcommand{\xa}{\ensuremath{X_1}}` since that can be used in either a text or math environment with no additional typing.  Using `\ensuremath` is often said to be not a good idea (it *does* make the source code somewhat less clear), but this is what it is designed for.

Comment: I use shorthand commands all the time, mostly to ensure consistency, often with optional arguments.  What I mean by consistency is e.g. the order in which subscripts appear so that I don't write $X_{it}$ one time and $X_{ti}$ the next.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is there a reason `\ensuremath` is often said to be not a good idea, other than making the source code unclear? (using it only to define a  shorthand command would also limit its impact on the source code, since it would only explicitly appear in the definition). I'm asking because I've also seen commands having strange interactions that I would have never imagined (and maybe never realized)  pointed out on this website.

Comment: For something that is clearly math and thus should always appear in math mode `\ensuremath` does not make a lot of sense (because you should be in math mode anyway), that's why I would always write `\newcommand{\xa}{X_1}` and not `\newcommand{\xb}{\ensuremath{X_1}}`. The case for `\ensuremath` for commands like this is usually presented as `$\xa$` being longer to type than `\xb` (be aware that `\xb` will swallow following space, so you need to type `If \xb\ is` or similar, so there goes part of the advantage already ...). That is true, but if you want to write more than just `\xb` ...

Comment: ... you need to switch to math mode anyway as both `\xb+1` and `\xb^2` don't work as intended. So you'd end up typing `$\xb+1$` and $\xb^2$ and only get an advantage for the simple `\xb` case, but at the cost of an inconsistency and loss of logical markup of math mode. `\xa` on the other hand would be consistently used as `$\xa$`, `$\xa+1$` and `$\xa^2$` and it is clear that the entire thing is maths. `\ensuremath` is very useful for macros that are not math per se and should work anywhere, that are for some reasons implemented using math mode. `\enusremath` then ensures ...

Comment: ... that the user does not need to worry (or even know) about the implementation of this macro and can just use it everywhere as expected. (One example would be `\textsuperscript` and `\footnote`.)

Comment: I would probably not define `\xa` to expand to `X_1` just to save a few keystrokes. Especially if I also want `X_2` (`\xb`?) and `X_n` (`\xn`?) I would end up with a lot of different macros. But I might define something like `\stochproc` to expand to `X` so that I can later easily switch notation for my stochastic process from `X` to `\xi`. Then I'd write `\stochproc = (\stochproc_t)_{t \geq 0}`. That makes the code a bit harder to read, because the variable names are probably longer, but things can be changed easier later on. ...

Comment: ... Of course that approach requires some thought to come up with good names and a decision whether or not a concept is important or relevant enough to warrant a macro. I'd not write `\anaturalnumber` to expand to `n` so that I can say `Let $x_{\anaturalnumber} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $\anaturalnumber \in \mathbb{N}$.`

Comment: One last thing: It is tempting to use very short macro names, but many one- or two-letter commands are already taken by TeX or LaTeX core commands and it is usually an extremely bad idea to overwrite those. I think longer macro names with more descriptive names would be more useful, but the typing advantage goes away for those (many editors have autocomplete features that may help here).

Comment: To back up @moewe  statement we collectively and others have potentially spent more days discussing this than would be saved had it simply been implemented **without question** at its time of conception HOWEVER the number of hours still to be spent investigating why in the future abbreviating \letter to \let may cause issues might be avoided by saying **do not abbreviate without question**

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've got a bit to think about. (Also, I had forgotten about the built in autocomplete feature of many editors. I'm not sure how useful this is for short things like $X_1$ though. Then again, an autocomplete for something like `\stochproc` could be very useful...).